# JS/Node.js How to get date/time in this format: 2017-03-13T04:43:30.916Z

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking to get the current time in this format. 
Like in Go you an import time and then time.now() will give you the current time in this format. I'm sure there is a library that will do this but I'm having a really hard time tracking it down on google/here. 
Does anyone happen to know what it is or can point me in the right direction? Thanks much.

Comment: check out moment.js

Comment: [toISOString method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: `new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()` check https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: @AndrewEvt `new Date().toISOString()` is enough

Comment: @AatishSai—responding to questions on dates with "use moment.js" is like responding to DOM questions with "use prototype.js" or whatever your library *du jour* happens to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toISOString